# Attempting to render animation with no visible results

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm sorry if this is a painfully obvious question, but I have created an Icosphere whose size varies based on an audio input I have baked in. I'm hoping to be able to render a video of the ball changing sizes with the audio source, and then composite that video onto a different video I have. However, when I attempt to render, I get no visible results. Here's the settings:

[image: the settings i have]

And here's what it looks like when I'm rendering it:

[image: rendering]

And here's the output visual:

[image: output]

Can anyone give me some tips about what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!